# How to launch two terminal commands with delay thru applescript or automator?

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line, automator, script

I need to launch two terminal commands thru applescript/automator with delay between them.

Absolutely don't know  how to do it thru applescript, so I tried to do it thru automator and here what it says when i try to launch *PRLCTL* command: ***'sh: prlctl: command not found'.

Commands:

```
open -a Parallels\ Desktop

prlctl start "Windows 10"
```

Launching them directly thru terminal is working.
Can somebody help me with figuring out how can I save it in one file and launch these two comand with it.

Comment: Why do you need to first open **Parallels Desktop** to use its `prlctl` _command line utility_. I would think that shouldn't be necessary, as it not for the `vmrun` _command line utility_ in **VMware Fusion**.

Comment: Thanks for ans answer below, realy, the main question is how to run prlctl utility with help of applescript or automator. I'm  absolute lamer in applescript. Can I ask your help with  this task? I realy need this command to work thru applescript or autoamtor but dunno how to do this.

Comment: Andrew, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PATH` passed to a `do shell script` *command* in **AppleScript**,  or a `do shell script` *command* in a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator** *workflow*, or a **Run Shell Script** *action* in an **Automator** *workflow* is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, and any executable called that is not within that `PATH`, then the *fully qualified pathname* needs to be used.

In **AppleScript** use the `do shell script` *command*, e.g.,:

```
do shell script "open -a 'Parallels Desktop'; /path/to/prlctl start 'Windows 10'"
```

In **Automator** you can use a **Run AppleScript** *action* with the same `do shell script` *command* as above.

Or use a **Run Shell Script** *action* with, e.g.,:

```
open -a 'Parallels Desktop'
/path/to/prlctl start 'Windows 10'
```

If you need a *delay* between the *commands* add, e.g., `sleep n` when `n` is the number of seconds to *delay*, e.g.,:

In the `do shell script` *command*, e.g.,:

```
do shell script "open -a 'Parallels Desktop'; sleep n; /path/to/prlctl start 'Windows 10'"
```

Or in the **Run Shell Script** *action*, e.g.,:

```
open -a 'Parallels Desktop'
sleep n
/path/to/prlctl start 'Windows 10'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Man you are my savior:)

Comment: Veryfied your answer as right one, but I cannot vote for it, dont have enough reputation. Thank you one more time!